Partner Center Add-on StoreListings Language Page Never Loads
I'm working on publishing my app to the Microsoft Store. I'm working on creating add-ons.
In Microsoft Partner Center, the language page for Add-ons under Store Listings doesn't work. When one clicks on a newly added language (e.g.: English), the page loads, but it remains blank.
To get there, follow this path: Home > Apps and games > MY_APP_NAME > Add-ons > MY_ADD_ON_ID. After clicking on a submission, the "Store listings" section shows up, but clicking on any language navigates to a blank page.
Can someone please confirm this issue and provide a way to report it? Trying to open a support case leads to a circular reference type of issue. Website A's help redirects to website B's help which redirects to website A's help.

I managed to complete the language-specific store listing through importing .csv. I exported the .csv of the default configuration, I entered the default translations as well as those for the locale I specified, then I imported the .csv. I couldn't define the image however. This part seems to be broken. I was able to submit my add-on to the store in the end.
